# get Data-permalink-path or url of tweet

Tags: python, selenium, url, tweets

I'm getting an error as AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_attribute
The part of code where the issue persists :

```
        for i in range(1,3):
            bot.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)') #scrolling
            time.sleep(5) #let content to load
            tweets = bot.find_element_by_class_name=('css-1dbjc4n')
            links = [elem.get_attribute('data-permalink-path') for elem in tweets]
            print(links)
ed = Twitterbot('xxxxx', 'xxxxx')
ed.login()
ed.like_tweet('webdevelopment')
```

elem is treated as str and str has no attribute as get_attribute

[Image showing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij9Ta.png)

Answer (score 0):

Error is self explanatory :

this will return

```
tweets = bot.find_element_by_class_name=('css-1dbjc4n')
```

a web element not list of web elements.

so changing that to `find_elements` should get the job done.

```
for i in range(1,3):
            bot.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)') #scrolling
            time.sleep(5) #let content to load
            tweets = bot.find_elements_by_class_name=('css-1dbjc4n')
            links = [elem.get_attribute('data-permalink-path') for elem in tweets]
            print(links)
```